# How to retrieve some content from a cloned harddrive

Tags: linux, mount

I have an external harddisk containing a clone of the internal hardisk (using `dd if=dev/sda of=dev/sdb`)

```
sda       8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   400M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3    8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0 298,3G  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0   1,8G  0 part 
├─sda6    8:6    0  28,6G  0 part /
├─sda7    8:7    0 286,1G  0 part /home
├─sda8    8:8    0   3,8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda9    8:9    0   450M  0 part 
└─sda10   8:10   0  20,2G  0 part 
sdb       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1    8:17   0   400M  0 part 
├─sdb2    8:18   0   260M  0 part 
├─sdb3    8:19   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb4    8:20   0 298,3G  0 part 
├─sdb5    8:21   0   1,8G  0 part 
├─sdb6    8:22   0  28,6G  0 part 
├─sdb7    8:23   0 286,1G  0 part 
├─sdb8    8:24   0   3,8G  0 part 
├─sdb9    8:25   0   450M  0 part 
└─sdb10   8:26   0  20,2G  0 part
```

Now I tried to retrieve the content of folder `/var/www` on `dev/sdb7` by mounting as follow:

```
sudo mount dev/sdb7/var/www /home/tmp
```

but this results in next error

> mount: /home/tmp: special device dev/sdb7/var/www does not exist.

Thanks helping me to solve this issue.

Comment: Devices aren't directories, you can't specify subdirectories of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man mount`:

> The standard form of the mount command is:
>
> ```
>           mount -t type device dir
> ```
>
> This  tells the kernel to attach the filesystem found on device (which is
> of type type) at the directory dir.

A directory isn't a filesystem, consequently not mountable.

You can `mount /dev/sdb7 /some/mountpoint`, then access `/some/mountpoint/var/www`.

You can bind mount a part of the file hierarchy elsewhere. The man page gives example `mount --bind olddir newdir`. However you can't bind mount a directory from an unmounted partition - the partition isn't part of the file hierarchy until it's mounted.